# camera movement

Tags: animation, camera

I just started working on animation for the first time and I need some help with camera movement. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oD3gSX3ICM, I used a Bezier Curve instead of the circle he used but he says that's okay. I got through all the step until I pressed play. My camera went way far away from the curve and had this weird dotted line connected to the curve[image]

This could be a very easy fix but again I'm very new to animation :)

Comment: The dotted line indicates that the camera is parented to an object. Which object? The object where the line ends. It can be turned off in the overlays. As for the going away part, try clicking the Keep transform option in the panel below

Comment: Maybe this video will help you with the bezier curve https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4PxYAKVG9Q&ab_channel=Christopher3D

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tutorial he doesn't parent the camera to the curve, he gives it a *Follow Path* constraint with the curve as *Target*, once done select the camera and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in order to reset the object location, the object needs to be at the center of the scene if you want to make it start at the beginning of the curve. Also in the curve *Data panel > Path Animation*, you must have tweaked the curve *Evaluation Time* value, which has moved the camera away, bring it back to 0.